# Limitation 1 transaction per day

Tags: transaction

I want to have some limitation for transaction. One product can only allow purchase 1 per customer per day. 
For example: Customer A can buy product A once per day, after payment that customer cannot buy the product anymore.

So it is not only restrict for product A only set for qty maximum to 1, it is also can check for Customer all order can only buy for product A for 1 per day.

Comment: Shall it be disallowed to add such a product to cart or can be added but can't be bought?

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine you'd want to use an Observer on the `sales_order_place_before` event.

If you observe that event and check if the customer has any orders in the past 24 hrs.

There's a little tutorial here that should get you on your way: http://www.techflirt.com/magento-event-observer-hook-in-magento/